# Input validation in C

Tags: c, input, validation

I'm writing a program in C. In the program, the user has to choose a number, either 1, 2 or 3. I would like to construct the code so that when the user enters in a number that isn't 1, 2 or 3, he/she will be told "Invalid selection - choose again" and then they will be brought back to the start of the program:

```
int main() {

    int choice;
    char response, Y, N;

    printf("Choose a shape from the following:\n 1.Sphere\n 2.Cone\n 3.Cylinder\n");

    scanf("%d",&choice);

    if(choice==1||choice==2||choice==3) {
        printf("Enter the radius, r\n");                             
    } else
        printf("Invalid selection, choose again.\n");

}
```

What I would like is that after "Invalid selection, choose again" appears, the user is brought back to the start of the program, so they can input their choice again. How would I do this?

Comment: use for or while or dowhile loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what you do:

```
int choice;
char response, Y, N;
for (;;) {
    printf("Choose a shape from the following:\n 1.Sphere\n 2.Cone\n 3.Cylinder\n");

    scanf("%d",&choice);

    if(choice==1||choice==2||choice==3) {
        break;                    
    }
    printf("Invalid selection, choose again.\n");
}
```

Once this loop is over, prompt for the radius. You will nearly certainly need another loop to prevent the input of negative values for the radius, so do not prompt for it in the same loop.

Comment: Thank you. This is what I'm looking for, as I need the "choose a shape" prompt to appear following "invalid selection".

Answer (score 1):

Use a while loop for this

```
int main()
{
    int choice;
    char response, Y, N;

    printf("Choose a shape from the following:\n 1.Sphere\n 2.Cone\n 3.Cylinder\n");
    while(1)
    {
        scanf("%d",&choice);

        if(choice==1||choice==2||choice==3)
        {
            printf("Enter the radius, r\n");                             
            //Maybe read the radius here
            scanf("%d",&radius);
            break;
        }
        else
            printf("Invalid selection, choose again.\n");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use `do-while` loop, loops until correct input
do like this,add choice 4 for exit:

```
 do {
        scanf("%d",&choice);
int flag=0;
        if(choice==1||choice==2||choice==3) {
            printf("Enter the radius, r\n");                             
        } else {
            printf("Invalid selection, choose again.\n");
            flag=1;
        }
    } while(flag==1&& choice!=4);
```

Comment: This is an infinite loop. Once `flag` is set, it never changes again.

Comment: Still won't work. What do you mean by `choice!=4`? It'll be an infinite loop. First wrong input sets the `flag` to 1 and any subsequent *correct* input won't break the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Some people will object to this, but I think in these situations a plain old `goto` is a very clean and readable way of doing things, because it emphasizes the linearity of the "normal" control path:

```
int main(int arg, char *argv[])
{
    int choice;

choose_shape:
    printf("Choose a shape from the following:\n"
           " 1.Sphere\n 2.Cone\n 3.Cylinder\n");
    scanf("%d", &choice);
    if (choice < 1 || choice > 3) {
        printf("Invalid selection, please choose again.\n");
        goto choose_shape;
    }

    printf("Enter the radius, r:\n");
    ...
}
```

Yes, people have complained about `goto` so let me justify it some more.

Here is a more sophisticated version that allows you to select a shape by letter:

```
    char c;
    shape_t shape;
choose_shape:
    printf("Choose a shape: [s]phere, [c]one, c[y]linder:\n");
    scanf("%c", &c);
    switch (c) {
    cases 's':
        shape = SHAPE_SPHERE;
        break;

    case 'c':
        shape = SHAPE_CONE;
        break;

    case 'y':
        shape = SHAPE_CYLINDER;
        break;

    default:
        printf("Not a valid shape: %c\n", c);
        goto choose_shape;
    }
```

And here is the version with `goto`.  Note that this introduces another variable, `flag`, whose only purpose is to get rid of the `goto` statement.  You cannot simply use `break` here (which is an unlabeled `goto` to begin with) because of the `switch` statement.  I consider this harder to read due to the additional state.  It's five lines longer.

```
    char c;
    shape_t shape;
    int flag;
    for (flag = 0; !flag; ) {
        printf("Choose a shape: [s]phere, [c]one, c[y]linder:\n");
        scanf("%c", &c);
        switch (c) {
        cases 's':
            shape = SHAPE_SPHERE;
            flag = 1;
            break;

        case 'c':
            shape = SHAPE_CONE;
            flag = 1;
            break;

        case 'y':
            shape = SHAPE_CYLINDER;
            flag = 1;
            break;

        default:
            printf("Not a valid shape: %c\n", c);
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: @DesertIce: If you can't articulate why not to use `goto`, then you're just repeating what someone told you.

Comment: Are you really asking why goto is not good practice? I'll give you two reasons on my mind : 1.As the size of the program increases using goto will make it difficult to understand the flow of the program. 2. It also drastically decreases the readability of the code for others.

Comment: @DesertIce: That's only a problem when you use `goto` to replace structured programming.  Here the "normal" control flow is linear, and so I argue that the `goto` version is cleaner and more readable.  It's common in the Linux kernel and when doing error handling, if you try removing it there you'll end up with a mess of spaghetti code.  Lesson: `goto` is *usually* harmful, but use your brain and look at things on a case-by-case basis.

Comment: At least goto has a label with a name. The other solutions will need break or continue which have *implied* labels.

Comment: I am just saying that it's a bad idea to suggest goto to a new user.

Comment: @DesertIce: I'm just saying that you should explain why.  The other examples suggest a loop where the only exit is `break`, which is essentially an unlabeled `goto`, or the use of a flag variable which is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative for you to consider.  Notice that the getting of user input is separated into a function and the `main()` just calls that function and loops on error.  Readers of `main()` probably don't care about how you get the input choice, so why make them read it?

Also notice that I used `fgets`, not `scanf`. If you run your version with `scanf` and enter a non-digit, that character will remain in the input buffer indefinitely; `scanf` will never remove it as it is looking for digits to satisfy the %d format string - hence an infinite loop.  You could try flushing `stdin` before the `scanf` (using `fpurge`) but the function would still not correctly handle the closing of `stdin`  (eg with ctrl-d on the shell UNIX based systems).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static int get_shape(int *shape)
{
    char buf[10] = "";
    printf("Choose a shape from the following:\n"
           " 1.Sphere\n 2.Cone\n 3.Cylinder\n");

    if (!fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin)) { /* Note: fgets, not scanf */
        exit(1); /* ctrl-d */
    }
    *shape = strtol(buf, NULL, 0);

    if (*shape==1 || *shape==2 || *shape==3) {
        return 1;
    }
    printf("Invalid selection\n");
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    int shape = 0;
    while (!get_shape(&shape)) {
        /* loop */
    }
    printf("Choice: %d\n", shape);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a simple validation using the while loop, I just copied your code and made a few adjustments, here the code will scan the integer from the user and will proceed to print `"Enter the radius, r"` only and only if the user types in the integers `1`, `2` or `3`, otherwise the program will keep on asking him to type in the correct input.

```c
int main() {

    int choice;
    char response, Y, N;

    printf("Choose a shape from the following:\n 1.Sphere\n 2.Cone\n 3.Cylinder\n");

    scanf(" %d",&choice);
    while((choice<=1)||(choice>=3)){

            printf("Invalid selection, choose again.\n");
            scanf(" %d",&choice);
    }
    printf("Enter the radius, r\n");

}
```