# Better way to process user input?

Tags: workflow

At the moment I have a single prompt method which prompts the user for input, and then calls a method to process that input.

Inside the process input method, if certain conditions aren't met, I call the prompt method again (which calls the process input method) and it gets into a recursion loop.

How else could I continually prompt for and process user input until a condition is met?

Comment: At the moment I've got multiple if else statements statements which check for different scenarios, and I'm not sure how to incorporate that while loop

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: the language is ansi c

Comment: the answers here might help then http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12998258/

Comment: yes I'm trying to work this through the code at the moment, and will update when I solve the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Ask for user input
while(True):
    Process input
    If input is valid:
        break
    Ask for user input
```

You could also return False from your function processing the input to indicate that user input was invalid and True otherwise:

```
Ask for user input
while(not Process_input()):
    Ask for user input
```

Comment: I ended up with the following logic: while (1)
if input is false
break
and processed the prompt function again which called the process input with the while loop! so thanks!